# Create C# structure for CvMat.data union or any way to access it in C#

Tags: c#, c++, data-structures, opencv, emgucv

I need to access 'data' property EmguCV MCvMat structure. But that property is a pointer(IntPtr). I found that structure for this property(data) is an union. It's like this:

```
union Data
{
    char* ptr;     // Data pointer for an unsigned char matrix
    short* s;      // Data pointer for a short matrix
    int* i;        // Data pointer for an integer matrix
    float* fl;     // Data pointer for a float matrix
    double* db;    // Data pointer for a double matrix
} Data;
```

I tried to create a structure for this in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct MCvMatData
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public char[] ptr;     // Data pointer for an unsigned char matrix
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public short[] s;      // Data pointer for a short matrix
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int[] i;        // Data pointer for an integer matrix
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float[] fl;     // Data pointer for a float matrix
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public double[] db;    // Data pointer for a double matrix
}
```

And then convert it using Marshel,

```
MCvMat mat = (MCvMat)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pMat, typeof(MCvMat));
MCvMatData matdata = (MCvMatData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(mat.data, typeof(MCvMatData));
```

But this gives me an exception. What I need to do is:

- Create data structure in C# for access this pointer or
- Any other way to access *MCvMat.data* property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've published [a Visual Studio 2010 solution on SkyDrive](http://cid-48a119f5ed65483e.office.live.com/embedicon.aspx/.Public/MarshalHelp.zip). It dmonstrates un-marshalling such a structure.

I'll try the MarshalAs attribute when I have more time. Usually, in such situations, I would implement an adapter layer in C++ to make it easier to transfer data between unmanaged and managed code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply Dan. I tried every possible ways to create structure, but it didn't worked. If you can suggest anything to do, it'll be great help for me. Thanks again for reply.

Comment: Write a pseudocode sequence and then I'll help you implement it in C#.

Comment: I do not have pseudocode for these structures Dan coz I use library to access them. But I was able to find codes. This is the structure for CvMat. [link](http://universuse.com/files/cvmat.c). I need to access data union in there. What I have now is pointer(IntPtr) for this CvMat object. I was able to unmarshal that pointer to MCvMat(which is C# version of CvMat) structure. But to data property in that MCvMat structure also a pointer(IntPtr). Now I need to get unmarshal that data pointer to object, so I can access values in there. Hope this information are enough. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan.. :) Able to solve it with your great example.. Thank you very much...

Comment: I have the exact same problem, Can you help me with that @Sach ? , I tried the code, I wonder how your code looks like

Comment: Hey, @Musaab sorry but i don't have any of codes i have used for this project. i will get back to you if i got remembered anything. sorry.